# Install SQL Server drive on SageMaker notebook instance running on Amazon Linux 2, Jupyter Lab 1 platform

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

I am using aws sagemaker notebook instance to run jupyter notebook. I have a MS SQL Server DB 2019 db that I am trying to connect to from the notebook.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
import json
import os


# sql database
import pyodbc
connection = pyodbc.connect(
                              'Driver={SQL Server};'
                              'Server=sname;'
                              'Database=dbname;'
                              'Trusted_Connection=True;'
                           )

cursor = connection.cursor()
```

I get an error, likely because the driver is not installed on the instance.

```
Error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_20407/3026941781.py in <cell line: 12>()
     10 # sql database
     11 import pyodbc
---> 12 connection = pyodbc.connect(
     13                               'Driver={SQL Server};'
     14                               'Server=sname;'

Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

how do I install the driver on sagemaker instance and resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this?